# How to check $PATH for installed software in a bash script?

Tags: bash, path

Recently one of my bash scripts failed because `cmake` and `zip` / `unzip` were not installed on a system.

What would be a convenient way to check for installed packages in `$PATH` env?

I would like to check `$PATH` directly for `cmake` and the like since my script is running on Debian, Ubuntu, Arch, and so on. Thus, I would prefer to not use a package manager, because I would have to implement it several times using `dpkg`, `pacman`, ... based on the distribution the script is currently executed on.

Comment: If you're just looking for tools like `cmake` and `zip` then those are installed by the package manager and the binaries will be in `/usr/bin` unless you built them from source and put them elsewhere. If you installed them via the package manager then you can just use the package tool like `rpm` or `dpkg-query` to search for the installed packages.

Comment: @NasirRiley yes, but the problem is that my script is running on different distributions. Hence, I would like to avoid implementing that with `rpm`, `dpkg`, `pacman`, ... It is quite cumbersome to maintain this by hand so I would prefer to not use different package managers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249)", the most portable way of testing whether a command is found in `$PATH` or not is through:

```
if command -v given-command > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo given-command is available
else
  echo given-command is not available
fi
```

If your script is for public consumption, you should obviously document the prerequisites so that another person is able to install the dependencies before running the code.